# AttributeError: type object 'DatasetV2' has no attribute 'from_tensor'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning Tensorflow 2.0 and I am getting an error as I run the following code:

```
data = np.random.randint(0,10, (3,4))
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor(data)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-9873d7e2b8bc> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor(data)
AttributeError: type object 'DatasetV2' has no attribute 'from_tensor'
```

The same here:

```
e= tf.data.Dataset.from_element(10)
AttributeError: type object 'DatasetV2' has no attribute 'from_element'
```

But I can run the code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
```

without a problem.

Comment: It's mispelled, try `.from_tensor_slices`

Comment: I think there is also `.from_tensors`

Comment: Thank you, it works with from_tensor_slices.  However the documentation has also the method .from_tensor.  Why it did not work?

Comment: As indicated by @IWHKYB, it's not `from_tensor`, but [`from_tensors`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensors). Note what this function does is different from [`from_tensor_slices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices).

Answer (score 1):

for your case tf.Data can be created in two possible ways which are `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors` and `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`.

`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors` will Create a `Dataset` with a single element, comprising the given tensors. Below is the example by taking your sample input.

```
data = np.random.randint(0,10, (3,4))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(data)
for i in dataset.take(-1):
  print(i)

#Print output  
tf.Tensor(
[[1 4 0 2]
 [6 3 5 6]
 [4 2 9 6]], shape=(3, 4), dtype=int64)
```

You can see it has created a single tensor of the given shape.

`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` as the name says it creates a slices of tensors.
The given tensors are sliced along their first dimension. This operation
preserves the structure of the input tensors, removing the first dimension
of each tensor and using it as the dataset dimension. All input tensors
must have the same size in their first dimensions.

```
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
for i in dataset2.take(-1):
  print(i)

#Print Output

tf.Tensor([1 4 0 2], shape=(4,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([6 3 5 6], shape=(4,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([4 2 9 6], shape=(4,), dtype=int64)
```

You can see it has created 3 tensors by slicing along first dimension of data of shape (3,4).